# Will hover will be extinct? Any research or case studies done on frequency of hover in desktop

Tags: mobile, interaction-design, hover, interactive-ui, microinteractions

I am typing this on my mobile so let me keep it short. I am talking about contents that is revealed on hover in desktop. So what we do in mobile UI is we make it visible at first sight. I want to know how much Mobile users likely to hover in desktop. Please note that They started browsing website in mobile from childhood. Since they are familiar with tapping I think they find less affordance to hover.   We all agree mobile users are increasing and crossed desktop users. In near future I think hover will be not part of interaction. What do u think? Please answer with previous research or case studies if possible.

Comment: Mobiles have far more limited space than desktop, yet you are showing everything on mobiles and hiding that content behind a hover on desktop? If there's enough space to display it on a mobile then surely there's enough space on a desktop to display it too? Why hide it behind a hover at all?

Comment: Let me give you an example. The logout button is hidden under profile with Chevron down next to it. I think hardcore mobile users prefer to click instead of hover. In this way I don't see any strong reason to reveal contents on hover

Comment: Ah OK, so it's not always visible on mobile - you're using a click on mobile but hover on desktop for the same functionality?

Comment: Yup u got my point. @Jonw

Comment: We are in an age of new users. A giant portion of the population has been sold on smart phones. That's the extent of the significance of mobile UI. Tiny touch interfaces and typing texts will disappear. Do you really think that holding and pressing a tiny screen with your thumb is the future? Touch is for today's mobile. Not tomorrow's. What is the significance of the tiny handheld touch devices that are popular these days? Have you ever tried to produce anything more than a text message with touch on handheld? Ever program, design, edit or produce anything?

Comment: I think you're unlikely to find any answer to this that isn't pure speculation, unless by pure chance someone is studying this weirdly specific thing in a hand-picked segment of the population that has mobile devices but hasn't been exposed to mouse-like hardware.

Comment: Revealing anything on hover will disappear but takes time. may be a decade.

Answer (score 1):

The `:hover` property of HTML is [a web standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#selector-hover) used by billions of web sites. Standards are unlikely to change in any short period of time.

Comment: Dear Rob, new generation has no idea about standards of web. They are just used to do whatever they feel easy.

Comment: @Jivan That has no affect on past standards. They may create something new but old standards will remain in effect long afterwards. (I agree that these new people who splintered off to the WHATWG have also splintered off from actual "computer science".

Comment: So you gonna have enough hovers in your upcoming projects, right Rob?

Comment: @Jivan I use `:hover` where needed and no other reason.

Comment: @Jivan - There are a lot of business applications that are still on desktop (and will be for quite a while). I use :hovers all the time.